# RedirectToAction not working with angular2 in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core

I am using Angular 2 with asp.net core.Here is the routing setup in asp.net core

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    template: "{*url}",defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
```

Here is action method. The action method is call from angular 2 http post

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Authentication([FromBody] UserViewModel model)
        {
            GenericResponseObject<JwtTokenViewModel> genericResponseObject = new GenericResponseObject<JwtTokenViewModel>();
            genericResponseObject.IsSuccess = false;
            genericResponseObject.Message = ConstaintStingValue.Tag_ConnectionFailed;
             AccountRepo accountRepo = new AccountRepo(_baseUrl, _memoryCache);
                if (accountRepo.JwtTokenGenerator(model) != null)
                {
                    UserViewModel userViewModel = accountRepo.UserAuthentication(model);
                    RedirectToLocal();
                }

                genericResponseObject.IsSuccess = true;
                genericResponseObject.Message = ConstaintStingValue.Tag_ConnectionSuccess;
            return Json(genericResponseObject);
        }

        private IActionResult RedirectToLocal()
        {

                 return RedirectToAction(nameof(DashBoardController.Index), "DashBoard");
        }
```

The RedirectToAction is not working. I get the response in json. The contoller should navigate to the action but I am getting the json result at the client side.

Here is my angular 2 routing

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent} from "./app.component";

import { LoginComponent } from "./Components/login.Component";
import { HomeComponent } from "./Components/home.component";

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'Home/Index', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'Account/Login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'Home/Index', component: HomeComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);


@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, routing],
    declarations: [AppComponent,LoginComponent, HomeComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Please can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I want to know if you found a solution for it? Would you care to share it here?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the action return Json instead of RedirectToLocal(), for example:

```
return Json(new 
{ 
    isRedirectToWhere = true 
});
```

then do redirect in ng2 when you get the response

Comment: But I want to redirect from server side . I dont want to do it from client side

Comment: Please provide me some solution ....... I don't want to redirect from ng2